# How to set a filter in Typescript that filters out a string if it's identical with a string in an array?

Tags: typescript, filter, rxjs

I got an array of observable objects that I have to filter out for specific id's that I hold in an array of strings.

So I have to check if every single object in my observable array has an id that matches with an id of my string array.

I tried this:

```
filter(docs => {
              docs.forEach(doc => {
                this.StringArray().forEach(string => {
                doc.id === string;
                });
              });
              return docs;
            })
```

But I get an compile error:
`...is not assignable to type 'boolean'` and have no idea how to solve this problem.

I'm relativ new to Typescript and if there is a better solution to this problem, I am open to any suggestion.
Also if more code is needed I would update it.

**UPDATE** for ethane:

```
 getSearchResult(searchRequest: Searchrequest) {

    return this.authService.user$.pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
       return this.angularFirestore
        .collection<any>('users', ref => ref.where('offers', 'array-contains', searchRequest.offerParam)
          .where('city', '==', searchRequest.cityParam)
          .where('sex', '==', searchRequest.sexParam))
        .snapshotChanges()
        .pipe(
          map(actions => {
            return actions.map(a => {
              const data = a.payload.doc.data() as User;
              const id = a.payload.doc.id;
              return { id, ...data };
            });
          }),
          filter(docs => {
              docs.filter(doc => this.getUsersToBeExcludedArray().includes(doc.uid));
            })
        );
      }
      )
    );
  }
```

**2. Update**

```
getSearchResult(searchRequest: Searchrequest) {
    console.log(this.getUsersToBeExcludedArray());

    return this.authService.user$.pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
       return this.angularFirestore
        .collection<any>('users', ref => ref.where('offers', 'array-contains', searchRequest.offerParam)
          .where('city', '==', searchRequest.cityParam)
          .where('sex', '==', searchRequest.sexParam))
        .snapshotChanges()
        .pipe(
          map(actions => {
            return actions.map(a => {
              const data = a.payload.doc.data() as User;
              const id = a.payload.doc.id;
              return { id, ...data };
            });
          }),
          // docs is an array
          filter(docs => {
            return this.getUsersToBeExcludedArray().includes(docs.id); // can't access docs.id
          })
        );
      }
      )
    );
  }
```

Comment: Is `StringArray` a prop on your class?

Answer (score 0):

RxJS's `filter` functions the same as `Array.prototype.filter`.

What you can do is:

```
docs.filter(doc => this.StringArray().includes(doc.id));
```

Where `docs` is your observable.

**Update:**

```
.pipe(
  map(actions => {
    ...
  }),
  map(docs => {
    return docs.filter(doc => this.getUsersToBeExcludedArray().includes(doc.uid));
  })
);
```

RxJS filter: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html

Comment: I still get the error. I edited my post to show you the hole function.

Comment: @ConstantinBeer, I've updated my answer. Because you've nested `filter` functions, the inner `filter` is meant to return an array to the outer `filter` (it won't because you aren't returning anything from the inner `filter`), the source of your types mismatch error. You should remove the nesting of `filter`s as above.

Comment: I have now implemented it as recommended by you. Now I get an error because `doc` is not found in `doc.uid`. And with `docs.uid` it doesn't work, because I don't have the uid.

Comment: @ConstantinBeer, updated answer. `doc` should now have `uid` or `id` whichever is correct for you.

Comment: The problem is, that the result of the mapping before returns an array of doc objects. That's why I can't use `.uid` on it. Is there a way to iterate that array of doc objects with `filter()` or something else and then filter it?

Comment: I don't understand why you are trying to access `uid` on each doc object when your map is returning `{ id, ...data }[]`. Just change `uid` to `id` as my previous comment pointed out. I put `doc.uid` in my answer because your question update included it there.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't make any difference for me if I use `uid` or `id`. My problem is that I can't access any of my id's because I get an array of docs. I edited my post with the actual code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190577/discussion-between-ethane-and-constantin-beer).